# Why add 0.1 when changing the margins of plots in R?

Tags: r, plot

I've seen this lots of times, and just noticed it's also on the help page of `par`:

```
The default is c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1
```

Why is it that the default has this 0.1 addition, and it's also common to see `+ 0.1` when changing `par(mar)`?

When setting `par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0) + 0.1)` I thought the idea was to set a minimum margin, but it doesn't make sense for values different than zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know, but [S: An Interactive Environment for Data Analysis and Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/053403313X) (Becker and Chambers 1984, the first book on S, which is the ancestor of R) gives these defaults (search for `xrig`) and says (p. 95)

[image]

(the appendix clarifies that this actually includes the additional 0.1, but doesn't give any additional explanation). I think that's the best you're going to do. [John Chambers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Chambers_%28statistician%29) is still around; while he [hasn't been active on the R-help mailing list since 2004](http://search.gmane.org/?query=&author=John+Chambers&group=gmane.comp.lang.r.general&sort=date&DEFAULTOP=and&xP=Zcamber&xFILTERS=Gcomp.lang.r.general---A) he [continues to contribute to the development list](http://search.gmane.org/?query=&author=John+Chambers&group=gmane.comp.lang.r.devel&sort=date&DEFAULTOP=and&xP=Zjohn%09Zchamber&xFILTERS=Gcomp.lang.r.devel---A) ... even if you bug him, I'm not sure he would remember the rationale for a minor design decision he (or one of his co-authors) made more than 30 years ago ...

My own guess, for whatever that's worth, is that one might expect e.g. 4 lines' worth of material outside the left edge of the plot (e.g. ticks, tick labels, and a two-line axis label), with the 0.1 as "additional margin" so that text isn't exactly hitting the edge.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had the same question as you, and when I looked for the answer I found your question. And from my understanding, the reason that default value has +0.1 is to keep at least x and y axis when you set `par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0) + 0.1)`. Look at the picture below:

[image: The picture! Click]

As you can see, though not that clear but still obvious, axis Y and X at the very margin of the picture. This means, when I set with code `par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0)`, I will get the largest size of the graph (if there's no default +0.1, there would even be no axis X and Y).

Hope this can help you